# Run a batch directly from network share via Windows Explorer

Tags: batch-file, networking, share, administrator

I'm trying to get some things easier on my job, but I'm stuck at a point.

We have a batch file shared on your domain server, used to install some basic programs in newly formatted computers. Everyone has full access to that share. As this batch install programs, it needs administrative privileges to run.

So, we go to Windows Explorer, type `\\myserver\myshare`, gives the administrator credentials, right click it, and "Run as administrator". As expected, it won't work. A cmd window opens and quickly closes, because the user administrator doesn't have the password for that share. In fact, that window says the username or password is incorrect.

Then I tried to create a second batch file, which in theory will run the first one as administrator without privileges. So, again we open Windows Explorer, type `\\myserver\myshare`, and double click it this second batch. But it won't work also, because it gives an error. Let me show you the code:

```
@echo off
cls

cmdkey /add:mydomain /user:mydomain\administrator /pass:administrator_password
net use z: \\myserver\myshare /savecred
z:
runas /savecred /user:mydomain\administrator mybatch.bat
```

In theory, this works, but don't. runas gives an error:

> -2147467259: not specified

The strange thing is the "net use" command don't ask for the password, as it have to. It maps, so I'm guessing the credentials are stored correctly.

I tried CPAU, PSEXEC, a lot of suggestions from here, and others also, but no success. Anyway to run my first or second batch directly from my share, on windows explorer? Or I really need to open a administrative prompt, map the drive, and then run the batch?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: I just Google searched the error you have given and Google only finds your question as the only result.

Comment: I tryed search also, but no progress.